# Communication and space allocation with multiple controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

iI'm very new in programming with multiple view controllers.
I have a RootViewController, and a FirstViewController. Inside RootViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) FirstController * firstController;


- (FirstController *)firstController {

    if (!_firstController) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
        _firstController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First View"];
    }

    return _firstController;
}
```

So, I manage to see the FirstViewController that I've designed in the storyboard.

The problem is this. If I try to run this instruction inside RootViewController:

```
    _firstController.myString = _myString;
```

myString is obviously the name of a property inside RootViewController and the same inside FirstViewController. Running this instruction doesn't work without allocating memory for _firstController. But, if I allocate memory and initialize _firstController, every adjustments made in the Interface Builder will be vanished.

How can I solve? I'm sure I'm trying to do something very wrong. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote getter - so use it!

```
self.firstController.myString = _myString;
```

instead of

```
_firstController.myString = _myString;
```

You're trying to access instance directly and of course there are no memory allocated for it because you are using technique called 'lazy loading'(ivar will be allocated when it needed.) By using `self.firstController` you simply send message [self firstController] which will allocate memory for first controller.